# Path of an application (here Python) is not accessible from the Finder

Tags: finder, python, path

I cannot see in the Finder the path "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework" (there is no folder "Frameworks" inside "Library") although this path is the output of the error message when trying to run a jupyter notebook

Here is the whole problem:

I installed Python 3.7 on my mac. I had previously version 3.6 as well as Anaconda which I tried to uninstall. When I call `python3` from Terminal it works. And after entering the following line: `sys.path`

```
['', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python37.zip', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages']
```

I can successfully open an jupyter notebook. However, when I tried to run the code on the Jupyter notebook, it seems that the jupyter is trying to look in the path of python 3.6 I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1543, in _execute
    result = yield result
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1099, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1107, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/services/sessions/handlers.py", line 73, in post
    type=mtype))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1099, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1107, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/services/sessions/sessionmanager.py", line 79, in create_session
    kernel_id = yield self.start_kernel_for_session(session_id, path, name, type, kernel_name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1099, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1107, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/services/sessions/sessionmanager.py", line 92, in start_kernel_for_session
    self.kernel_manager.start_kernel(path=kernel_path, kernel_name=kernel_name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1099, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 315, in wrapper
    yielded = next(result)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/services/kernels/kernelmanager.py", line 148, in start_kernel
    super(MappingKernelManager, self).start_kernel(**kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyter_client/multikernelmanager.py", line 110, in start_kernel
    km.start_kernel(**kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyter_client/manager.py", line 259, in start_kernel
    **kw)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyter_client/manager.py", line 204, in _launch_kernel
    return launch_kernel(kernel_cmd, **kw)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyter_client/launcher.py", line 128, in launch_kernel
    proc = Popen(cmd, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1344, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7'
```

I cannot see in the finder the path "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework" (there is no folder "Frameworks" inside "Library")

I posted a similar question with more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55191226/path-of-python-is-trying-to-access-an-old-version-and-this-path-is-not-accessib?noredirect=1#comment97125254_55191226)

Answer (score 2):

Finder menu > Go > Go to folder and copy & paste this file path

answer found [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8514945)